# Is this the right code for tracking a button in a an app for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm new to Firebase SDK, I have to create a custom event for downloading content and I can someone explain to me how I would go about changing the code to track the downloads?

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
  AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\title!",
  AnalyticsParameterItemName: "title",
  AnalyticsParameterContentType: "cont",
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the automatically collected event in Analytics called 'first_open' which is triggered when the user launches the app for the first time after installing or reinstalling it. You could check out this [page](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) to know more about automatically collected events in Firebase.